# Windows 10 displays a 3D Windows 10 logo after 15 minutes of inactivity and I can't disable it

Tags: windows, windows-10

If I don't touch my computer for 15 minutes then it displays a 3D Windows 10 logo and I can't find a way to prevent this from happening... I've gone in my settings then to system then to power & sleep and changed all the settings to "NEVER" but it still displays a 3D logo after 15 minutes of inactivity... Here's what the logo looks like:
[image]

(I used the prt sc button to capture that) I've only had this inactivity problem since I installed this on my PC: https://www.push-entertainment.com/live-wallpapers/space-journey-3d/ but after I uninstalled the program the inactivity problem started up. I've tried reinstalling the program then uninstalling it again but nope my PC still shows that logo after 15 minutes of inactivity

Comment: Why the -1? There's nothing wrong with this question... It's just I don't have enough rep to show photos so I put the link to the photo instead... Not my fault.

Comment: Anyone know how to help without factory resetting?

Comment: Just to be sure: do you have the Screen saver option set to None? To get there go to Start and type "Turn screen saver on or off".

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your desktop. In the menu click Personalize.

Click on Lock screen (on the left) and scroll down to the bottom of the window.

Click on Screen saver settings.  Click on 3D Text and select None, then click OK.

Answer (score 0):

Open Run dialog box with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> & type **`control desk.cpl,,@screensaver`** (works in Win10). You can see the Screen Saver Settings window.

[image: Screen Saver Settings]

Now select the screen saver drop down menu and set it to ***None***.

[image: None screen saver]

Now click on the Apply button and the screen saver will be disabled. You may also disable it with registry settings. Go to `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]`. And delete these registry values::

```
SCRNSAVE.EXE
ScreenSaveActive
LockScreenAutoLockActive
ScreenSaveTimeOut
ScreenSaverIsSecure
```